# Azure Function App timer trigger in Python not working

Tags: python, azure

I can't get an Azure Function App to run my Pyhton script (timer trigger function) inside of Azure. Locally, the script works just fine. My script is a simple operation which copies data from a PostgreSQL-database to an Azure SQL Database. (script is also listed below).

After creating a function with the TimerTrigger template in VS Code, I get this __ init __.py file, looking like this:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

So, as I understand correctly from the (standard generated) function.json file, the init.py file will be the fired at the desired trigger. The function.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "* */10 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I paste in my own script in the __ init __.py file, it works like a charm **locallly**, but once uploaded to Azure *nothing happens, at all*. After pasting my own script, the init.py file looks like this (I hid my credentials of course):

```
import datetime
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)

# Start of script
# Connect PostgreSQL
pg_host = "###"
pg_port = "###"
pg_dbname = "###"
pg_user = "###"
pg_pw = "###"
db_conn = psycopg2.connect(host=pg_host, port=pg_port, dbname=pg_dbname, user=pg_user, password=pg_pw)
pg_cursor = db_conn.cursor()

# Query PostgreSQL
pg_sql = 'select "_id", "minute", "hour", "day", "month", "year", "action", "dashlaneRid", "href", "id", "ip", "roleType", "sessionId", "tag", "textContent", "toggle", "url", "userId", "userPib", "utcEpochMillis", "xtag" from click'
pg_cursor.execute(pg_sql)
query = pg_cursor.fetchall()

# Fetch PostgreSQL query in Pandas DataFrame
click_df = pd.DataFrame(query, columns=[
    '_id'
    ,'minute'
    ,'hour'
    ,'day'
    ,'month'
    ,'year'
    ,'action'
    ,'dashlaneRid'
    ,'href'
    ,'id'
    ,'ip'
    ,'roleType'
    ,'sessionId'
    ,'tag'
    ,'textContent'
    ,'toggle'
    ,'url'
    ,'userId'
    ,'userPib'
    ,'utcEpochMillis'
    ,'xtag'])

# Azure SQL connect
az_server = '###'
az_db = '###'
az_user = '###'
az_pw = '####'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+az_server+';DATABASE='+az_db+';UID='+az_user+';PWD='+ az_pw)
az_cursor = cnxn.cursor()

# Truncate table click
az_cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE stage.click;")
cnxn.commit()
print('Table succesfully truncated')

# Fill table click with values
for index, row in click_df.iterrows():
    az_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO stage.click"
    "(_id, minute, hour, day, month, year, action, dashlaneRid, href, id, ip, roleType, sessionId, tag, textContent, toggle, url, userId, userPib, utcEpochMillis, xtag) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
    ,row._id, row.minute, row.hour, row.day, row.month, row.year, row.action, row.dashlaneRid, row.href, row.id, row.ip, row.roleType, row.sessionId, row.tag, row.textContent, row.toggle, row.url, row.userId, row.userPib, row.utcEpochMillis, row.xtag)
    cnxn.commit()
az_cursor.close()
pg_cursor.close()
print('Table successfully filled')
```

I configured CORS for the Function App to allow all domains, because when I Test/Run the function, I was getting HTTP error 413 Request entity too large. That's solved: I now get HTTP response 202 Accepted. However: nothing happens on the SQL Database.

I probably forgot to mention a few important things, so please ask away.

Comment: Is the Function not triggered? Or is it triggered but just doesn't do anything? If you add some logging statements you can at least see some relevant information like if the connections are made correctly. Also: if you're copying data, you might want to have a look at [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory).

Comment: @rickvdbosch How do I check if it's triggered? Do you have any suggestions for these logging statements? Keep in mind that locally, my connections work just fine. I'm aware of ADF, but I need a low budget solution.

Comment: You can use application insights live metrics to check if your function is triggered. If there are any errors, that would be logged here as well. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/live-metrics-stream/. Just for clarity, what is the frequency you are looking at for this to trigger? A 10 min schedule would require "*/10 * * * *", but I see your schedule as "* */10 * * * *"

Comment: @AnupamChand upon checking the logs (which i had not enabled, thanks for that), I saw that the error was related to the psycopg2 library. Fortunately, it is resolved by adding psycopg2-binary to the requirements.txt file. Now, however, there seems to be another problem with the pyodbc library I'm importing. Any ideas maybe? I can give you the errormessage if you want. As for the schedule: I tried putting it like "/10 * * * *", but that's invalid, so I put " */10 * * * *", which works fine actually.

Comment: Yes sorry. "*/10 * * * *" is correct, but "* */10 * * * *" is not and that is what you have mentioned in your function.json in your question. For the new error, It has nothing to do with your function not triggering. So I would suggest raising a new question and the title of this question will be misleading.

Comment: Okay so triggering works fine now! Thanks for your help guys. As for the errors regarding pyodbc: I specified the wrong driver. It should be DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}. Might be helpful for anyone using the pyodbc library.

Comment: `"* */10 * * * *"` as in the question is a correct schedule specification. See [Timer trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions) where they give `0 */5 * * * *` as an example, described as "12 times an hour - at second 0 of every 5th minute of every hour of each day."

Comment: @JohnWiseman jep, correct! Thanks for confirming that. The schedule I used worked perfectly fine, so that was not the issue here.